# How often do you see bookholders being used in libraries in the US?

Tags: study

So I come from a country where I see from time to time students using bookholders in the classroom during lectures especially during studying.

[https://www.amazon.com/Book-Stand-BS1500-Bookstand-Textbooks-Bookstands-Music/dp/B01CCJJGGA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CCJJGGA)

In college in the US I rarely saw these kinds of things being used, but I might be wrong -- are these widely used in the US?

Answer (score 1):

Bookstands like those illustrated in the Amazon link are quite uncommon in US collegiate libraries. Not unknown, but it is indeed unusual to see them.

Source: my observations from my own college and professional school experience to visiting my two kids' schools (collegiate and graduate level) when they attended.